# Invalid initializer compiler-error at malloc of struct array

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, malloc, initializer

I'm trying to read an arbitrary number of string items into an array of structs when my program  initializes. I want to allocate heap memory for the

When the compiler gets to the following line, it throws an `error: invalid initializer`.

The first part of my code:

```c
int main() {
    printf("Work starts in the vineyard.\n");

    typedef struct {
        char* name[20];
        unsigned int jobs;
    }Plantation;

    // read from list of plantations
    FILE  *plantationFile = fopen("./data/plantations.txt", "r");
    if (plantationFile==NULL) {perror("Error opening plantations.txt."); exit(1);}

    char line[20];
    char *lp = line;
    int plantationCount;
    Plantation plantations[] = (Plantation *)malloc(sizeof(Plantation));
    if (!feof(plantationFile)) {
        int i = 0;
        fgets(line, 20, plantationFile);
        scanf(lp, "%i", &plantationCount);
        realloc(plantations, sizeof(Plantation) * plantationCount);
        while( !feof(plantationFile) ) {
            fgets(line, 20, plantationFile);
            strcpy(*(plantations[i].name), lp);
            plantations[i].jobs = 1u;
            ++i;
        }
    }
...
```

What am I missing here?

The compiler output:

```
$ gcc -W -Wall vineyard.c
vineyard.c: In function ‘main’:
vineyard.c:30:32: error: invalid initializer
     Plantation plantations[] = (Plantation *)malloc(sizeof(Plantation));
                                ^
```

It also throws the same if I leave out typecasting.

```
$ gcc -W -Wall vineyard.c
vineyard.c: In function ‘main’:
vineyard.c:30:32: error: invalid initializer
     Plantation plantations[] = malloc(sizeof(Plantation));
                                ^~~~~~
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining `plantations` as an array, and you're trying to initialize an array with a pointer.  An initializer for an array must be a brace enclosed list of initializers.  More importantly, while arrays and pointers are related, they are not the same thing.

Define `plantations` as a pointer instead of an array:

```
Plantation *plantations = malloc(sizeof(Plantation));
```

Also, `realloc` can change where the allocated memory points to, so you need to assign the return value back:

```
plantations = realloc(plantations, sizeof(Plantation) * plantationCount);
```

You should also check the return value of `malloc` and `realloc` for errors.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. The malloc function's return type is pointer, and I'm trying to assign that to an array type variable. I guess I got confusedIf I keep plantations as a pointer, will I be able to use the plantations[i] syntax, or am I limited to pointer arithmetic? If so, is there a way I can use the [ ] syntax?

Comment: @Bundologus Yes, `*(A + B)` is exactly equivalent to `A[B]`.